# No instance for (Convertible Int Double)

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

Can anyone explain this error message? According to Hackage, Data.Convertible.Base, version 1.0.11.1 has an instance declaration for `Convertible Int Double`.

```
λ> :set -package=convertible-1.0.11.1
package flags have changed, resetting and loading new packages...                                                                    
λ> import Data.Convertible.Base
λ> let b = 3 :: Int
λ> convert b :: Double

<interactive>:18:1:
    No instance for (Convertible Int Double)
      arising from a use of `convert'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Convertible Int Double)
    In the expression: convert b :: Double
    In an equation for `it': it = convert b :: Double
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Haddock documentation displays the instances defined in the package. It doesn't necessarily mean that they're defined in the same module as the datatype. You should

```
import Data.Convertible
```

or at least

```
import Data.Convertible.Instances
```